# Speed up contrast map calculation with NumPy + Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to compute a contrast map from an RGB image given as a numpy array using NumPy + Cython.

By constrast map I mean the following: Each pixel in the resulting map is a floating point value which is calculated by adding up the euclidean distances in color values between the corresponding pixel in the input image and all other pixels in the input image in a certain surrounding (in this case a small rectangle) around that pixel.

I realize that this is a computationally expensive operation but still, the function I've come up with is painfully slow (i.e. running in the order of seconds even for small input images).

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


cpdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] contrast_map(
        np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim=3] img, np.int64_t radius = 5):

    cdef np.int64_t width = img.shape[0]
    cdef np.int64_t height = img.shape[1]

    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] result
    result = np.empty((height, width), dtype=np.float64)

    cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim=1] v
    cdef np.float64_t acc

    cdef np.int64_t r, c, r_, c_
    for r in range(height):
        for c in range(width):
            v = img[r, c]

            acc = 0.0
            for r_ in range(max(0, r - radius), min(height, r + radius + 1)):
                for c_ in range(max(0, c - radius), min(width, c + radius + 1)):
                    acc += np.linalg.norm(v - img[r_, c_])

            result[r, c] = acc

    return result / result.max()
```

Have I made any mistakes which impact performance?

Also, I realize that there are libraries offering ready-to use functions for this sort of thing. This question is more for educational purposes.

Comment: This is a brute force approach with a runtime complexity of `O((h*w)^2 + radius^2)`. It will be slow regardless of how it is implemented. Find a better algorithm, there are lots openly available, implement that in the simple python only case first, then worry about optimising it.

Comment: Apart from the computational complexity of your algorithm, you have `min`, `max`, `np.linalg.norm` and `result.max()` calls that are pure Python function calls. So your innermost loop is still not C-optimised.